# Reference column in mysql where clause by its index

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, ordinals

All tables in my database always have an id (autoincrement), at column 0 regardless of its name, it's always there.

So, in table *teste* I probably have *idTeste*, in table *cars* I should have *idCars*, but the format is not a standard, I could have a table *example* with a column simply called *id*.

I'm trying to create a generic update like:

```
update tablename set bla='ble' where column[0]='id';
```

so, don't matter the column's name, I wish to reference it by its id. Is that possible?

I know I can do something like:

```
show columns from table
```

and pick the first name before execute my update, and, in fact, I did that to solve my problem, but I'm  curious if it was possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're after is called the ordinal position, or simply "ordinal".

SQL does not support using ordinals in the WHERE clause.  Support for ordinals differs between database vendors -- the most common support is in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY 2, 1
```

...which relies on the column(s) listed in the `SELECT` clause.  Some support ordinals in the `GROUP BY` clause.

That said, using ordinals is not a recommended practice because it's dependent on the order of the columns in the SELECT clause.  If that order changes without the ORDER BY/etc being updated, you won't know until runtime.

Comment: Yeah, I believe this is not possible. I discover a way to get the column name by its ordinal position, but I couldn't use it in my update where clause. I used `select COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME="mytable" and ORDINAL_POSITION=1` but something like `update SQLstat set Script="buga" where (select COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME="SQLstat" and ORDINAL_POSITION=1)=12` don't work... I'll keep my current solution... Thank you!